# PHP array JSON encode and that object decode inside ExtJs

Tags: javascript, php, json, extjs

I have php array as bellow

```
$php_arr = json_encode(array('1'=>'"data1', '1'=>'data2'));
```

that json object i try to access inside Extjs as bellow

```
var test = Ext.JSON.decode()(<?php echo $php_arr; ?>);
```

but that gave to me error as 
`Uncaught Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String:`

because of JSON object break `"data1`

How can I get this JSON object decoded in ExtJs without lose "?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var test = Ext.JSON.decode(<?php echo $php_arr; ?>);
```

and you *must* escape `"` like so

```
$php_arr = json_encode(array('1'=>'\"data1', '2'=>'data2'));
```

Also in PHP you can use [addslashes](http://php.net/addslashes), like so

```
$php_arr = json_encode(array('1'=>'"data1', '2'=>'data2'));
$php_arr = addslashes($php_arr);
```